# Regular Expression to get part of exception message

Tags: java, regex

In one of the application that I am working on , it is throwing a validation Exception at some points and it will be like this :

```
   com.package.server.xmlapi.exception.ValidationException:
    Validation Error #1
    key=cost.greater.than.budget
    params=[Task][TaskFee]
    description=Current cost exceeds the budget 
            at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:222)
at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:129)
```

I would like to extract the description part to a string and currently doing this :

```
    if (exception.contains("description")) {
        message = exception.substring(exception.lastIndexOf("=")+1);
    }
```

But this will break if there is some additional parameter after description like Error: "This is another error" and then it will catch this also, but I only need description part. The description message can be at various lengths and it is from another application and I don't have any control over it. Can anyone suggest a Regular Expression for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one trick you need. Say what you mean:

```
description=(.*)
```

This will capture the text you need. The related java code goes like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("description=(.*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(exception);
if (matcher.find()) {
    message = matcher.group(1);
}
```

You can play with the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/X6zQZD/1).

Answer (score 1):

Use a [positive lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for this:

```
(?s)(?<=description=).*
```

will match everything that follows the string `description=`. The `(?s)` mode modifier is necessary to allow `.*` to also match newline characters. Remove that if you only want to match the text on the same line as `description=`.

Answer (score 0):

A **much** better approach is to have the exception class offer properties for the desired fields, like e.g. the `java.text.ParseException` does.

If the class is under your control, you could add these properties (use `ParseException` as template).

If the class is provided by a library, check if it maybe has `getKey()`, `getParams()`, `getDescription()`.

If both is untrue, **then** you really would have to go ahead with the RegEx approach...

Comment: Thanks Florian. But unfortunately, i don't have any control over the exception and it doesn't have methods like getKey(). So I am continuing with RegEx.